# Retrieve dynamic images from broker in web 8.1.1

Tags: content-delivery, dxa, web8, broker, dxa-1.5

I want to retrieve images dynamically from the Broker which are published as dynamic multimedia Components.

I am not sure about the model, I have tried to repeat the same way the default image model is created by but no luck not getting the image object although metadata is available.

### Update

`MediaCentreImage` is the name of the Schema which we have created.

```
[SemanticEntity(SchemaOrgVocabulary, "ImageObject", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
[SemanticEntity(CoreVocabulary, "MediaCentreImage", Prefix = "c")]
public class MediaImage : MediaItem
{ }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve and what you have tried?

Comment: @RickPannekoek As i mentioned i need to retrieve/display images based on parameters selected by end user like size,location etc. for that we have created new media schema we got the metadata details but image object is not available .i tried to repeat with the default image model available in DXA but image property is returning as null 
I have created new model name `MediaImage` which  is inheriting the `MediaItem`.model like in `Image` model

Comment: Please show the definition of your View Model.

Comment: @RickPannekoek  Here MediaCentreImage is the name of the schema which we have created.
 `[SemanticEntity(SchemaOrgVocabulary, "ImageObject", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
    [SemanticEntity(CoreVocabulary, "MediaCentreImage", Prefix = "c")]
    public class MediaImage : MediaItem
    { }`

Comment: is this a multimedia schema or your image is part of content schema?

Comment: @RajKumar  I have created new multimedia schema

Comment: Is is just mapping issue or you are not even  getting required values from Content DB?

Comment: Does your `MediaItem` class have no properties? How are you instantiating these objects?

Comment: @RajKumar  i am getting the other metadata details but image object is not available when query to content DB.

Comment: @RickPannekoek `MediaItem` class is the one which we are inheriting similairly like in DXA `Image` Model and yes there are other properties as well defined for metadata but those fields are populating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have created a default view for the Model, which uses and returns object based on the same. Add any metadata that you have in your schema, add to the model class itself.
Once done, try using your model class object, in another model which has a link to a component based on your multimedia schema.
For example, instead of:

```
 [SemanticProperty("s:image")]
 public Image Image { get; set; }
```

use:

```
 [SemanticProperty("s:image")]
 public MediaCentreImage Image { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm impressed that you managed to distill this answer from the question! The question is still prett unclear to me, but looking at this (accepted) answer, it seems the question was how to get an embedded Entity Model mapped properly?